# Stop timeout on mouse leave jQuery

Tags: jquery, function, timeout, mouseover, mouseleave

I'm trying to start a function with timer when mouse is over the span and when it leaves the span the function timer stops.

My problem is that the timer doesn't stop.

Where is the error?

```
<script>
$("#first").mouseover(function() {
  var tid = setTimeout(loop, 1500); 

  function loop(){
//code
    tid = setTimeout(loop, 1500);
  }
});
$("#first").mouseleave(function(){
  clearTimeout(tid);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring `tid` , `loop` function outside of `.mouseover` , using `.one()`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
 background-color: black;
}

#min img {
 border: 1px solid black;
}

#miniatura{
 height:290px;

 position:relative;
}
#min{
 height:243px;
 width:310px;
 text-align:center;
}

#min img{
 border:1px solid #646464;
}
.title_bg{
 margin-left:1px;
}
/*
AGGIUNTO
*/
ul.vid-rotater li {
 color: white;
}


/*
FINE
*/
.frame {
 display:block;
 height:243px;
 float:left;
 width:310px;
 z-index:3;
/* background: url("no_image.gif"); */
}
.frame img{
 border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}


.pic {
 clear:both;
 cursor:pointer;
 display:block;
 float:left;
 height:243px;
 position:relative;
 width:310px;
}
.pic .frame {
 left:0px;
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
}

.pic img {

 height:232px;
 left:1px;
 position:absolute;
 top:10px;
 width:308px;
 z-index:2;
}
.pic:hover {
 text-decoration:none;
}

.vid-rotater {
 position:absolute;
 visibility:visible; /*hidden*/
 margin:0 0 0 25px;
 padding:3px 5px 5px;
 left: 0px;
}
.vid-rotater li, .vid-rotater a {
 display:block;
 float:left;
 width:29px;
}
.vid-rotater li {
 margin:0 0 0 2px;
 padding:0;
}
.vid-rotater a {
 overflow:hidden;
 padding:4px 0 3px;
}
.vid-rotater span {
 background:#FFFFFF none repeat scroll 0 0;
 border-bottom:1px solid #333333;
 border-right:1px solid #333333;
 display:block;
 height:3px;
 line-height:999em;
 overflow:hidden;
}
.vid-rotater .active span {
 background:#CC3366 none repeat scroll 0 0;
 border-color:#660033;
 cursor:pointer;
}

</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    var tid = 0;
    var first = 0;
    $c = 0;

    function loop(){
      if (first == 0){
        $immagine = $(".lazy");
        first = 1;
      }
        $(".active").next().attr("class", "active");
        $(".active").prev().attr("class", "");

        $immagine.next().attr("style", "vivibility: visible;");
        $immagine.prev().attr("style", "visibility: hidden;");
        $c++;
        if($c > 7){
          $c=0;

          $(".active").prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().attr("class", "active");
          $(".active").next().next().next().next().next().next().next().attr("class", "");

          $immagine.attr("style", "visibility: hidden;");
          $immagine = $(".lazy");
          $immagine.attr("style", "visibility: visible;");
        }else{
          $immagine = $immagine.next();
        }
          tid = setTimeout(loop, 1500);
    }

    function handleMouseOver() {
      tid = setTimeout(loop, 1500);
    }

    $("#first")
    .one("mouseover", handleMouseOver)
    .on("mouseleave", function(){
      clearTimeout(tid);
      $(this).one("mouseover", handleMouseOver)
    });
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="first">
  <span id="min" class="pic">
    <ul class="vid-rotater" style="visibility: visible;">
           <li class="active"><span>0</span></li>
           <li class=""><span>1</span></li>
           <li class=""><span>2</span></li>
           <li class=""><span>3</span></li>
           <li class=""><span>4</span></li>
           <li class=""><span>5</span></li>
           <li class=""><span>6</span></li>
           <li class=""><span>7</span></li>
    </ul>
    <a class="frame" href="http://www.cycling.it/" target="_self" style="text-decoration: none;"></a>

    <img class="lazy" src="http://www.cycling.it/foto_gallery/big/01-revelator_prestige_Di2_7805.jpg" data-original="" style="display: block; visibility: visible;">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR9ty91M-QHPrgy6woAJAgdF68UrTD8c91WXz5dfznU1R_2GQ5Qjw" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <img src="https://eradellabicicletta.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/bici-da-corsa-rb1000-team-edition.jpg" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <img src="http://www.bicielettriche.bikeitalia.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/bici-elettrica-piaggio.png" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <img src="http://www.loriscycles.com/docs/gallery/2/bici_sx_101.png" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <img src="http://www.bikeitalia.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/bici-da-corsa-da-donna-stella-wilier.jpg" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <img src="http://www.wildpigs.it/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/status.jpg" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <img src="http://www.milkywayshop.it/media/catalog/product/cache/2/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/i/bici-fixed-margot-cycling-margot-dragonfly-12165.jpg" style="visibility: hidden;">


  </span>
</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am trying your code but in my page don't work. It seems not intercept the mouseleave event

Comment: @Davide _"trying your code but in my page don't work. It seems not intercept the mouseleave event"_ Can you create a stacksnippets https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ , or jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: this is the link https://jsfiddle.net/ezuk7ua9/ here it works but locally it doesn't work, why?

Comment: @Davide Appear to stop cycle , here, when image is not hovered. Can describe "doesn't work" ?

Comment: for "doesn't work" i mean that when i leave the mouse from #first the images continue to swicth

Comment: Not certain why not returning same results locally as jsfiddle

Comment: locally the script is into the html. It could be the problem?

Comment: That should not allow images to continue cycling. Though could try to move `js` to `head` element , wrapped in `$(document).ready()`

Comment: i had put this code in the head but now also image cycling doesn't work
http://pastebin.com/cJS6niNz

Comment: Missing closing `)` at `$(document).ready(function() {})` at pastebin

Comment: yes, sorry. now the cycling work but it doesn't stop when the mouse leave... i don't understand because work only in jsfiddle

Comment: @Davide Just tried locally at chromium and firefox, same `html` , `js` as at http://plnkr.co/edit/Wmktdy0NeYO2YjSPOCi8?p=preview ; stops cycling at `mouseleave` , here

Comment: i had try your link on chrome and firefox and it run correctly but locally and on altervista doesn't work

Comment: What is "altervista" ?

Comment: now it work the error war that i used $tid and $first instead of var tid and var first. can you explain me the differences?

Comment: Can use either as variables names , as long as consistent through `js`.

Comment: ok, thanks for the answers. last thing: why if i click on the image the link doesn't open?

Comment: _"why if i click on the image the link doesn't open?"_ ? `img` elements are not `a` elements

Comment: ok, if i would add a link at #first i must use jquery or there is something in html that can resolve this?

Comment: Try wrapping `<img>` elements with `<a></a>` element having `href` attribute set to resource location

Comment: with wrapping it work!
i have another problem with this code, i have more than one #first span in the page with the same id (i'll change it in a class). how can i put ine the function only the span with the mouse over?

Comment: Try changing selector to `span.first`

Comment: I listened your advice, but the img cycles in every span. i made some changes at html. http://pastebin.com/7Bwubaha
this is the jQuery script http://pastebin.com/1PqNUL6a

where I'm wrong?

Comment: @Davide Not certain what issue is ? Can you create a jsfiddle to demonstrate issue ?

Comment: @Davide Not certain what expected result is ? Appears to be different than `html` at original Question ?

Comment: Which `span` element should event occurs at ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `var tid` makes that variable local inside the `mouseover` handler function only.

It is therefore not accessible in the `mouseleave` due to javascript scopes.

Effectively you are doing `clearTimeout(undefined);`